# Controlling Contract

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-contract

Using truffle and makes me use truffle console but I dont want to and wouldnt either. Is there any other way interact with contracts and controlling their propreties and everything with an app or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Remix, a web IDE which allows you to deploy a contract or call a deployed contract's functions using their interface. You can access it there: https://remix.ethereum.org/

It includes many of the important features of Truffle, such as Unit Testing, Linting...

You will probably also want to read a bit of the doc, at least for the core functions of Remix: https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: will try right away thx

Comment: webjs can help with that either may be you can try that eaiser than remix